# Android turn detection math

Tags: android, math

I would like to develop a personal app for this i need to detect my car's rotation.
In a previous thread i got an answert to which sensors are good for that it's okay.
Now i would like to ask you to please summerize the essential/needed mathematical relationship.
What i would like to see in my app:
- The car rotation in degrees
- The car actual speed (in general this app will be used in slow speed situation like 3-5km/h)

I think the harder part of this is the rotation detect in real time. It will be good to the app could work when i place the phone in a car holder in landscape or portrait mode.

So please summerize me which equations,formulas,realtionships are needed to calculate the car rotation. And please tell me your recomendation to which motion/position sensor are best for this purpuse (gravity,accelerometer,gyro,..)

First i thought that i will use Android 2.2 for better compatibility with my phones but for me 2.3.3 is okay too. In this case i can use TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR which looks like a good thing but i don't really know that it can be a useful for me or not?

I don't want full source codes i would like to develop it myself but i need to know where can i start, what deep math knowlegde needed and what part of math are needed. And for sensor question: i'am a bit confused there are many sensors which are possible ok for me.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no deep math that you need. You should use `TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD` and `TYPE_GRAVITY` if it is available. Otherwise use `TYPE_ACCELEROMETER` but you need to filter the accelerometer values using `Kalman` filter or low pass filter. You should use the direction of the back camera as the reference. This direction is the `azimuth` returned by calling `getOrientation`, but before calling `getOrientation` you need to call `remapCoordinateSystem(inR, AXIS_X, AXIS_Z, outR)` to get the correct `azimuth`. Then along as the device is not laying flat, it does not matter what the device orientation is (landscape or portrait). Just make sure that the phone screen is facing the opposite direction of the car direction.
Now declare two class members `startDirection` and `endDirection`. In the beginning, `startDirection` and `endDirection` have the same values, now if the `azimuth` change by more than say `3 degrees`, there is always a little fluctuation, then change the `endDirection` to this value and continue to change until say 20 returned `azimuth` have the same values (you have to experiment with this number). This mean that the car stop turning and then you calculate the difference between `startDirection` and `endDirection`, this gives you the `degree of rotation`. Now set `startDirection` and `endDirection` to this new azimuth and wait for next turn.

Comment: Yes i understand what you say about startDirection/endDirection it's okay. What i not understand is why should i use 2 sensor (for example you sad gravity/magnetic) in a same time? Other thing that as i understand it accelerometer is harder to use for this purspuse? So it's still okay and will compatible with older devices but it's harder to calculate the turning in degree. I think this is where i have to better understand some math (to calulate degree based on accelerometer values). This is what you wrote,right? "Kalman filter or low pass filter"

Comment: What more thing, if it count that i will use this just very low speed situtation. For example when i parking my car (backward,parallel)

Comment: In 2.3.3 there is one more interesting thing: TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR maybe is it usable for me? Now i see my first problem/question: don't know what should i measure? What units/sensors are changing when i turn with my car.

Comment: If you use TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR you will get some drift. The unit is in radian.

Comment: Yes i tried it's working. But this is why i asking for math. Now all of my axes are changing. I think for the car turning i have to calculate with X and Z when the phone in portrait mode.  And maybe X and Y when the phone in landscape mode. But what kind of math functions/calculations/formulas/definitions should i use for this kind of calulations? Thanks!

Comment: No if you remap as I answered above and the device is not flat then there is no need to change axis.

Comment: With Accelerometer and Magnetic field using low-pass filter it's far to good. My problem that it's still very sensitive and not accureate it continues changing (azimuth) even i don't touch the phone! maybe because i am too close to my compter... Which combination are the most accurate?

Comment: If you use on the car you should try TYPE_GRAVITY. The azimuth will fluctuate a bit, it should not be more than 3 degrees. You can average over a history of say 10 reading, then you will get pretty stable result. I think I did give a formula for calculate the average, you may look at all my answers concerning sensors to find it, since I do not remember which questions.